# Looking for solution for cross platform development windows application and web application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, web, cross-platform

I got project that will run on windows and web. I wonder if there is a solution to create that as a cross platform application . If you have any experience or any solution please let me know.

Comment: Could you add a little more detail? You're building something that needs both a desktop and a web interface? Are you starting fresh or do you have an existing code base?

Comment: Maybe take a look at Xojo, depending on your needs. It can make Windows and Web apps and let you share code between them. http://www.xojo.com

Answer (score 1):

Create web service(s) for your business.

Consume them in both windows application and web application.

Configuring is the key here.

When it comes to consuming web services,may be little challenging for authentications, authorizations and marshalling data, but it is possible.

You can choose any programming language for creating web services. But languages like Java, C# or vb.net has good supporting libraries and easy to do. Any how your question tag says C#, dotnet frame work has good support for webservices using WCF.

Answer (score 0):

You can share a lot of UI code between a desktop and web application using a framework like [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/). This is the method that [a lot of popular products](https://electron.atom.io/apps/) with both web and desktop apps (like Slack, Discord, and Ghost to name a few) use.